# Haskell Lens. Get an element before the last

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

Is there a way to get the element before the last using hakell lens? For example, I have such a structure:

```
pp = (1,2,3,4)
```

I want to do something like `pp ^. _almostLast` and get `3`. I can't use _3 because (suppose) I don't know how much elements there are in this tuple.

Comment: People ask such questions occasionally, and I admit the more I program in Haskell the more baffled I am by them. How do you work yourself into a situation where you don't know how long your tuple is?

Comment: It's not possible not to know how many elements there are in a tuple. Tuples of different lengths have different types, and there is no type of "tuples of an unknown length".

Answer (score 1):

If you want your code to be flexible over the number of elements in a tuple, one option is to create your own type class, similar to the [`Field2`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-5.0.1/docs/Control-Lens-Tuple.html#t:Field2) class in `Control.Lens.Tuple`, which provides the `_2` function.

This class and the instances for the first few tuples [look like this](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-5.0.1/docs/src/Control.Lens.Tuple.html#Field2) (after removing some comments and irrelevant code):

```haskell
-- | Provides access to the 2nd field of a tuple.
class Field2 s t a b | s -> a, t -> b, s b -> t, t a -> s where
  _2 :: Lens s t a b

instance Field2 (a,b) (a,b') b b' where
  _2 k ~(a,b) = k b <&> \b' -> (a,b')
  {-# INLINE _2 #-}

instance Field2 (a,b,c) (a,b',c) b b' where
  _2 k ~(a,b,c) = k b <&> \b' -> (a,b',c)
  {-# INLINE _2 #-}

instance Field2 (a,b,c,d) (a,b',c,d) b b' where
  _2 k ~(a,b,c,d) = k b <&> \b' -> (a,b',c,d)
  {-# INLINE _2 #-}
```

If we now want to make a variant which instead picks the second-to-last element, we just have to tweak the code to do that:

```haskell
 -- | Provides access to the 2nd to last field of a tuple.
class AlmostLast s t a b | s -> a, t -> b, s b -> t, t a -> s where
  _almostLast :: Lens s t a b

instance AlmostLast (a,b) (a',b) a a' where
  _almostLast k ~(a,b) = k a <&> \a' -> (a',b)
  {-# INLINE _almostLast #-}

instance AlmostLast (a,b,c) (a,b',c) b b' where
  _almostLast k ~(a,b,c) = k b <&> \b' -> (a,b',c)
  {-# INLINE _almostLast #-}

instance AlmostLast (a,b,c,d) (a,b,c',d) c c' where
  _almostLast k ~(a,b,c,d) = k c <&> \c' -> (a,b,c',d)
  {-# INLINE _almostLast #-}
```

etc. for as many tuples you need.

---

But the big question here is: Why don't you know how long your tuple is? In most such cases, you would be much better off using a list, especially so you don't have to manually write a bunch of instances for each possible length of tuples you expect to encounter.